# Increment numerical value in Data Extension for open count

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, dataextensions, cloudpage

We have a problem with open rate reporting through a third party platform when we create multi-language dynamic emails, which means that because we have one HTML template for all locales, SFMC will treat that as one send, with one set of open rate data.

The way I'm thinking of getting round this, is to see if I can set a cloud page as an image src within the HTML and have the cloud page write to a Data Extension with the language variant and increment an open count number value by one.

Now, a few questions;

- Can I get a Cloudpage just to output a 1x1px transparent image alongside the Ampscript code?
- Will our send volumes be a blocker for this in terms of how many writes are potentially happening at once (a single market can have 1.4 million contacts at send)?
- In light of the above what's the best way to increment a value? I feel like reading the existing value, adding one and writing that back to the Date Extension will cause inaccuracies due to read/writes happening at the same time

The instance I'm working on is for a large corporate who are anti Google Analaytics, so using any built in SFMC tools is a red tape minefield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If language is written to the Send Log, then you can distinguish an open by language with a query that joins the _Open data view to the Send Log.

Also, going down this route, you're committing to building a custom process to generate your open rates.

More info: [**Send Logging**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_send_logging.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks Adam, that looks like the official solution, let's see if I can get this through the red tape!

Comment: One thing I forgot to ask. Is send logging available within Automation Studio sends?

Comment: Yes, it's a check box in the send definition.

Comment: Think I need our admin to check my perms as I'm not seeing the option, but can see it listed in the docs https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_configure_delivery.htm&type=5